the OpenCV findChessboardCorners() function doesn't work properly with my images
I am trying to recognize a chessboard pattern using OpenCV and Python.
I use the built-in findChessboardCorners feature which returns nothing if it doesn’t find the hole board.
Right now, I use this code:
img = cv2.imread(path_board)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)      
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, number_of_corners,
                                        flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH +
                                            cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK +
                                            cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE)
if ret == True:
    print("Chessboard detected")
   img_with_corners = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img_with_corners, (BOARD_SIZE + 1,BOARD_SIZE + 1), all_corners.reshape(-1, 1, 2), ret)
else:
    print("No chessboard detected")

Most of the time, the function only sets the value of ret to False, which means that it didn’t find anything. The board is only recognized in about a sixth of the cases.
Does anyone know how to improve the recognition? I suppose that I need to reduce noise, but that’s what medianBlur does already. Is it an issue with the function itself?
Here are a few images I used:

enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

The findChessboardCorners function should work with all images.

I would guess the problem is that the north and west sides don't have a border.  The edge detection needs a border.

[mre] required. number_of_corners is undefined. this is important information to have. -- your board is "broken". it has no "quiet zone" around it, but instead a mirrored version continuing right at its supposed edge. that's where two squares of the same color sit beside each other.

My board is 15*15, so the value of the variable is (14,14).
@TimRoberts I thought that the function works based on the inner corners only. Then, I don't understand why it works sometimes.

The documentation even states that there must be a solid color border around the board to get complete results.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga93efa9b0aa890de240ca32b11253dd4a

Thank you, while reading the documentation, I found that findchessboarcornersSB is the better option, because it can handle noise and is made to work with a white background instead of black borders.

none of these functions are made to work with "black borders". they all expect a white "quiet zone", under the assumption that the pattern was printed (black) on paper (white).

@ChristophRackwitz That's right, the function is simply more robust and almost always the better option.
